# How to Save all the values till the message.length in for loop?

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
           for(int j=0;j<msgObject.length();j++) {

             JSONObject d=msgObject.getJSONObject(j);


             Slongitude=d.getString("SfltLogitude");
             Slattitude=d.getString("Sfltlattitude");
             Elongitude = d.getString("EfltLogitude");
             Elattitude = d.getString("Efltlattitude");

             double lat = Double.parseDouble(Slattitude);
             double  lon=Double.parseDouble(Slattitude);
             double  Eat=Double.parseDouble(Elattitude);
             double   Elot=Double.parseDouble(Elongitude);

             Dlat.add(lat);
             Dlong.add(lon);
             DElat.add(Eat);
             DElong.add(Elot);

         }
```

please tell me how to save all the values of Dlat,DLong,DElat,DElong?? as from these values i need to plot a path on MAP.

Comment: can you explain your Question properly. and you want to parse data and store it in any value?  then put your json here

Answer (score 1):

Make a class named as MapData and make it `Serializable`  and make variables inside class and use arraylist of object type to store data and use that array list where ever you want to :-

```
public class MapData implements Serializable{

public double lat;
public double lon;
public double Elat;
public double Elon;
}
```

and do like below:-

```
ArrayList<MapData> mapDataList=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<msgObject.length();i++){
   JSONObject d=msgObject.getJSONObject(j);
   if(d!=null){
     MapData mapData=new MapData();
     if(d.has("SfltLogitude") && !d.isNull("SfltLogitude"){
       mapData.lon=d.getString("SfltLogitude");
     }
     if(d.has("Sfltlattitude") && !d.isNull("Sfltlattitude"){
       mapData.lat=d.getString("Sfltlattitude");
     }
     if(d.has("EfltLogitude") && !d.isNull("EfltLogitude"){
       mapData.Elon = d.getString("EfltLogitude");
     }
     if(d.has("Efltlattitude") && !d.isNull("Efltlattitude"){
       mapData.Elat = d.getString("Efltlattitude");
     }
     mapDataList.add(mapData);
   }
 }
}
```